# extract data from csv file based on two lists with priority for items in the first list

Tags: python

I have csv files and I want to extract part of data form each one into another file based on keywords from two different lists. That is, the the program should match every line in the original file with the keywords in the first list and write those lines until a match is found. once match is found, it should break the execution. In case the program reached the last line in the csv file without finding any match, then it should start matching with the second list and repeat the same.
I want to give the priority to the first list and if there is no match then start the process using the second list.

```
The first list fruit=['orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana','phone', 'TV', 'w']
The second list veg=['tomato','potato','onion']
```

following is a sample of the contents of one of the files called srcfile1

```
 paper
 wood
 plastic
 fire
 water
 house
 onion
 ginger
 mints
 banana
 TV
 watermelon
 phone
 pepper
```

I have written following python code:

```
import os
from tqdm import *
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nb
line = fr.readline()
fr = open('d:\\srcfile1')
fw = open('destfile1', 'w')
found=False
while line:
      line = fr.readline()
      if any (item.lower() in line.lower() for item in fruit):
          found=True
          fw.close()
          break
      elif any (item.lower() in line.lower() for item in veg) and found==False:
            fw.close()
            break
      fw.writelines(line)

fr.close()
fw.close()
```

The desired outcome from the code should be:

```
 paper
 wood
 plastic
 fire
 water
 house
 onion
 ginger
 mints
```

But When I run this code, it just match any element from both lists and does not give the priority to fruit list. It just give the following output:

```
 paper
 wood
 plastic
 fire
 water
 house
```

I would be grateful if anybody could help me in this.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand the goal, but you may need to loop twice the list in the original csv, so maybe store the results in a list, and then execute your search loops to find keywords / break if found / or loop with the second list

Comment: your `fruit` and `veg` do not correspond to your desired output... it is hard to know what you really want. and why do you close your outfile `fw.close()` all the time?

Comment: What I want is to stop at the first occurrence of any keyword in the first list. If nothing is found, then try the same with the second list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use set and intersection method to find your result

```
fruits = {fruit.lower() for fruit in fruits}
with open('d:\\srcfile1') as f:
       data = {key.lower() for key  in f.read().split('\n')}
data.intersection(fruits)
```

Comment: that would change the order and remove duplicates. but the question a bit vague... so that might be a solution!

Comment: Because they are keywords, i think is assumed that is uniques and it is not important the order for this problem

Comment: Actually I need to preserve the order also.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant, to write lines which are not present in`fruits` list and also lines which is not in uppercase letters and  to preserve the order you can use differnce of `set` intersetion and   `sorted` with key as `lines index`.

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nb
fr = open('d:\\srcfile1')
lines = fr.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.islower() ]
output = sorted(set(lines) - set(fruit).intersection(set(lines)), key=lines.index)
fw = open('destfile1.txt', 'w')
for line in output:
    fw.write(line+'\n')
fw.close()
```

Output:

```
paper
wood
plastic
fire
water
house
onion
ginger
mints
watermelon
pepper
```

Comment: Actually what I need is to iterate the file until I encounter any keyword from first list. If there is no matching, then iterate using the second list. letters case is not important. Of course I need to preserve the order in the file.

Comment: What if there is a matching?

Comment: If there is a matching, it should stop iterating. But if it reached the end of file without finding any match with the first list, it should start iterate the file and match with keywords in second list.